# A GDI+ error sometimes happening while making a screenshot

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

We have a bit of code which makes screenshot during error reporting. The application is WinForms in .NET 4 framework and is run on Windows Terminal Server. The app is used concurrently via the rdp connection. The code is fairly old and sometimes it gives the following error:

> ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
>
> Stack: WinBase.PrikazIznimke.NapraviScreenShot()
>   WinBase.PrikazIznimke.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Inner exception stack: System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename,
>   ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>   WinBase.PrikazIznimke.NapraviScreenShot() Stack:
>   WinBase.PrikazIznimke.NapraviScreenShot()
>   WinBase.PrikazIznimke.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Inner exception stack: System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename,
>   ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>   WinBase.PrikazIznimke.NapraviScreenShot().

The reasons for this error we never understood, we investigated several times without conclusion. The error itself is rarely encountered (maybe 1% of total reports). The code in full is this one:

```
private void NapraviScreenShot()
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

        this.ObrisiScreenShot(); 

        bitmap.Save(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"greska.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Logiraj i proslijedi");
        if (rethrow)
            throw;
    }
}

private void ObrisiScreenShot()
{
    try
    {
        string put = Application.UserAppDataPath;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(put + @"greska.jpeg") == true)
            System.IO.File.Delete(put + @"greska.jpeg");
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException) 
    {
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Logiraj i proslijedi");
        if (rethrow)
            throw;
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas what we could do next or any theories why would the error happen I would be grateful.

Comment: Using the `using` keyword to ensure that the `bitmap` object is disposed is not optional.

Comment: You're right I think. I can't believe I didn't see it so far.

Comment: Same goes for your [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=netframework-4.8) instance: "You should always call the Dispose method to release the Graphics and related resources created by the FromImage method."

Comment: Another thing, `Application.UserAppDataPath` doesn't add `"\"` to the path, so your file path is mangled. You should use `Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath,"greska.jpeg")` (if this is the real code).

Comment: Make sure to have permissions to save a file at the given path